# Is there a better way to generate a chess board?

Tags: javascript, chess

I am planning on creating a chess game inside of JavaScript in order to test my current skill level, which is not very high. I am trying to dynamically render elements without React because it is difficult to create a React application without create-react-app, so instead I a using document.createElement().

Using document.createElement creates something like this:
[the original chess board that I tried to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNDpn.png)

```
class Grid {
    constructor (length, height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
    }
    render() {
        let total = this.length * this.height;
        for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            const whiteSquare = document.createElement('div');
            whiteSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#ff9c9c;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            whiteSquare.id = `ws${i}`;
            const blackSquare = document.createElement('div');
            blackSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#fa6666;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            blackSquare.id = `bs${i}`;
            const br = document.createElement('br');
            console.log(`${i}`)
            i % 2 != 0 ? document.getElementById('board').appendChild(whiteSquare) : document.getElementById('board').appendChild(blackSquare);
            i % this.length == 0 ? document.getElementById('board').appendChild(br) : console.log('not it');
        }
    }
}

let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render()
```

I want a chess board that alternates colors, and I know that every 8 it generates it uses another one of the square it used before, so it alternates. However, I am not entirely sure how to implement this into my code.

Comment: You might wanna use a canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the rest with two and the rest of the value divided by 8 and take the ceiled value. Or in other words, respect the row.

BTW, please do not use conditional operator for not using the expression. In this case use simple `if` statement instead.

```js
class Grid {
    constructor (length, height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
    }
    render() {
        let total = this.length * this.height;
        for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            const whiteSquare = document.createElement('div');
            whiteSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#ff9c9c;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            whiteSquare.id = `ws${i}`;
            const blackSquare = document.createElement('div');
            blackSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#fa6666;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            blackSquare.id = `bs${i}`;
            const br = document.createElement('br');
            console.log(`${i}`)
            document
                .getElementById('board')
                .appendChild(i % 2 === Math.ceil(i / this.height) % 2
                    ? whiteSquare
                    : blackSquare
                );
            if (i % this.length == 0) document.getElementById('board').appendChild(br);
            else console.log('not it');
        }
    }
}

let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render()
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: If the intent is to generate a grid of dynamic dimensions, then hardcoding the value `8` will lead to undesirable outcomes — instead, the value should be derived from the input dimension.

Comment: yes. take the value from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a 2d board, why not use 2 (nested) loops?

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(length, height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
  }
  render() {
    let color = 0;
    for (let row = 0; row < this.height; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < this.length; col++) {
        const square = document.createElement('div');
        square.classList.add(color % 2 == 0 ? "white-square" : "black-square");
        square.id = `${color++ % 2 == 0 ? 'w' : 'b'}s${color}`;
        document.getElementById('board').appendChild(square);
      }
      color++;  // Remove this to have columns same color
      document.getElementById('board').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
  }
}

let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render()
```

```css
.white-square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ff9c9c;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.black-square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #fa6666;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit the fact that `rowNumber + columnNumber mod 2` will give you the desired checkered pattern, by virtue of the fact that an even number plus an odd number is an odd number.

```js
class Grid {

    board;
    length;
    height;

    constructor (length, height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.board = document.getElementById('board');
    }
    
    createSquare() {
      const el = document.createElement('div');
      el.classList.add('square');
      return el;
    }
    
    render() {
    
        for (let column = 1; column <= this.length; column++) {
          for (let row = 1; row <= this.height; row++) {
            let index = row+column;
            let colour = 'black';
            if ( index % 2 !== 0) {
              colour = 'white';
            }
            let square = this.createSquare();
            square.classList.add(colour);
            this.board.appendChild(square);
          }
        }
    
    }
}

let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render()
```

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.white {
  background-color: #ff9c9c;
}

.black {
  background-color: #fa6666;
}

#board {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```